# Erro ao executar OracleDataReader.HasRows com cursor sem valores

Tags: c#, oracle11g

Estou usando o OracleDataReader para inserir elementos de um cursor em uma lista. O cursor é retornado de um procedimento do oracle db. O problema é que quando não tenho elementos retornados no cursor, o aplicativo pára de funcionar sem dar erro. Eu quero saber como verificar se o cursor tem elementos?

Este é o código de função que cria a lista a partir dos elementos retornados no cursor e está em c# asp.net.

```
 public List<VagaModel> BuscarVagas(string codCentroCusto, string anoPeriodo, string codPeriodo)
    {

        List<VagaModel> lstVagas = null;

        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "NET_BUSCAR_VAGAS_P1";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("vCodCentroCusto", OracleDbType.Int64).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters["vCodCentroCusto"].Value = Convert.ToInt64(codCentroCusto);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("vAnoPeriodo", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters["vAnoPeriodo"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(anoPeriodo);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("vCodPeriodo", OracleDbType.Int64).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters["vCodPeriodo"].Value = Convert.ToInt64(codPeriodo);


                    cmd.Parameters.Add("vCursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    con.Open();


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    OracleRefCursor cursor = (OracleRefCursor)cmd.Parameters["vCursor"].Value;



                    using (OracleDataReader dr = cursor.GetDataReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            lstVagas = new List<VagaModel>();

                                while (dr.Read())
                                {
                                    var codVaga = dr.GetValue(0);
                                    var qtdSolteiro = dr.GetValue(1);
                                    var qtdCasal = dr.GetValue(2);
                                    var qtdBeliche = dr.GetValue(3);
                                    var qtdAuxiliar = dr.GetValue(4);
                                    var capVaga = dr.GetValue(5);
                                    var codTbVaga = dr.GetValue(6);

                                    VagaModel vaga = new VagaModel(codVaga.ToString(), qtdSolteiro.ToString(), qtdCasal.ToString(), qtdBeliche.ToString(),
                                        qtdAuxiliar.ToString(), capVaga.ToString(), codTbVaga.ToString());

                                    lstVagas.Add(vaga);
                                }
                        }

                        //dr.Close();
                        //dr.Dispose();

                    } 

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    throw new Exception(e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {


                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return lstVagas;
    }
```

Comment: coloca o stacktrace por gentileza

Comment: @Lucas Miranda Não da erro. A aplicação fica no HasRows como se fosse um loop infinito. Na verdade a aplicação fica tentando acessar o método HasRows e não sai e nem da erro.

Comment: Não da pra dizer o problema sem o erro, mas como você não tem erro vou deixar uma dica. Já tentou usar apenas o dr.Read()? Ele retornará false se não houver linhas, você nem precisa do HasRows nesse caso.

Comment: Porquê utilizar um cursor? Porque não uma consulta "simples" (`SELECT x FROM...`)?

Comment: @JoãoMartins Não entendo muito de oracle ainda, no entanto, o BD é de terceiro eles me passaram apenas as procedures. Então eu monto os Parameters e espero receber um cursor como OuPut. Por isso uso o dataReader para inserir os valores do cursor em uma lista. Por favor me corrija se estiver errado. Grato.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Já usei dr.Read() e acontece a mesma coisa. Poderia ser um erro na execução da procedure? É porque não tenho acesso ao BD, somente tenho as procedures para usar os dados.

Comment: Pode ser sim. Rode testes direto na procedure com os mesmos dados que está usando na aplicação pra debuggar.

Comment: Consegui identificar que esse caso acontece quando a procedure não retorna dados. Porém como consultar se obteve retorno ou não? Tanto com dr.Read(), quanto com dr.HasRows, se não obteve retorno, a aplicação fica acessando o método até dar timeout e seguir os próximos passos.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Sabe me dizer se existe uma maneira de identificar de a procedure não retorno nada? Acredito que esse é o ponto para resolver meu problema.

Comment: No oracle você tem acesso para realizar test e debugger na procedure?

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Não tenho permissão para debug na procedure, mas consigo executar e analisar o retorno. Essa proc lista as vagas disponíveis para agendamento. o meu problema é que se não houver vagas disponíveis, a proc não obtém retorno. Acredito que seja nesse ponto que o dataset tenta acessar o retorno da proc mas não possui retorno. Já tentei com dataTable e dataAdapter e ocorre o mesmo problema. Conhece alguma forma de verificar se a proc tem retorno ou não, no c#?

Comment: Você não tem um ambiente de dev do BD pra poder executar/debuggar/alterar a procedure? O ideal é identificar por que não vem retorno nenhum, em algum momento deve dar um exception e isso não é tratado, retornar um valor onde você possa identificar que ocorreu erro seria o ideal.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Concordo com a sua colocação, porém o cliente não irá disponibilizar esse acesso e a informação que tenho é que a procedure retorna um cursor se tiver dados para exibir, caso não possua dados para exibir, a proc finaliza sem retornar o cursor e os dados. Por isso estou com um pouco de dificuldade para trabalhar esta exceção. O que preciso, seria alguma forma de verificar se a proc retornou algo antes de executar o Read().